# How do I set up django-all-access?

Tags: python, django, oauth

I feel pretty dumb for not understanding the docs but could someone help me setup django-all-access? I want to allow facebook login. The step I don't understand is putting my API key in the database. I'm not sure what to put and where to put it.

[Here's the documentation link.](http://django-all-access.readthedocs.org/en/latest/providers.html)

Also, here are some screenshots of what I'm seeing.

[image: Facebook dev. interface]

[image: Django admin interface]

Also, the docs says I can just go to /accounts/login/facebook and it will work but do I need to map anything of create a view for this?

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If anyone cares, I decided to use Django Social Auth instead.